# How to correct issues of Proximity sensor

Tags: proximity-sensor

I have Lenovo a1000.When I am calling,the screen doesn't turn off.I checked for proximity sensor error on Lenovo companion app,its not correct.Please help.

Answer (score 0):

That would be hardware damage. Bring it to your local electronics repair shop or send it back to the manufacturer for repair.